How to enter username/password into Windows 11 "User Account Control"window?
I'm working on a security clamped system and am writing an application in Python to collate various log files.  When raising the access rights using the example below I get the Windows 11 "User Account Control" window displayed and if I manually enter the username/password information all is good with the world.  However, I need to automate this process and am struggling.  I was hoping to use PyWinAuto which I am reasonably familiar with but this does not seem to recognise the window (see code snippet below).
def main():
    app = Application(backend='uia').connect(title='User Account Control', timeout=1)
    dlg = app.window(title='UserAccountControl')
    dlg.print_control_identifiers(())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if not pyuac.isUserAdmin():
        ic("Re-launching as admin!")
        pyuac.runAsAdmin()
    else:
       main()  # Already an admin here.



Microsoft doesn't want viruses to be able to automate their way onto your system, so they purposefully make this as difficult as possible.

The "imagine if this were possible" thought experiment is helpful here: If this were possible, it's exactly what all malware would do.

The entire point of UAC is that it requires a human being to interact with the system to allow privilege elevation, and that it can't be automated around. You won't be able to do this.
